# Google Chrome - uploading apps to chrome web store but how to allow all domain with manifest.json?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I have Chrome web store package with zip file ready. But the problem is that manifest.json i need to allow two domain + all subdomains.

This is the reference:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Where its saying: "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"]
But how do i say in matches to allow two domain with all there subdomains? example:

*.stackoverflow.com and *.centos.org?

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at wrong parts of the documentation.

[Match Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)
[Match patterns and globs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match-patterns-globs)

Note that `"matches"` property is an array.

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.stackoverflow.com/*", "*://*.centos.org/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
```

The above will match all pages on `stackoverflow.com`, `centos.org` and all of their subdomains. Important to note that just `stackoverflow.com` will be matched.
`*` in place of `http` will match exactly either `http` or `https`.

Comment: I am still getting this: GET chrome-extension://xxxxx/icon.png 
net::ERR_FAILED chrome-extension://xxxx/icon.png:1
{
    "constraintName": "",
    "message": "",
    "name": "InvalidStateError"
}

Comment: Getting this _where_? I fail to see how it's relevant to the question. If you have another question, ask another question.

Comment: In my Javascript console, when i launched the Apps and executing the apps then getting this error in the console. I have applied my zip file like you have mentioned.

Comment: How is this in any way relevant to your original question?